# Revolution slider parallax slow

Tags: wordpress, parallax, revolution-slider, visual-composer

*I'm working on a Wordpress website which is completely made out of Visual Composer*.

- On one page I must use parallax effect which includes 4 different
  sliders with one slide (I'm using it that way as the template that I've imported is looking the same as my client want).
- But the thing is, parallax effect is so laggy and totally ruining the
  looks. On example, the slider looks normally but when I change slider
  layers than it becomes laggy. Any thoughts how to fix this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you use the correct picture dimensions (... px x ... px)
- I also compress my images before uploading it to my Wordpress website ([kraken.io](https://kraken.io/) has a good free online tool for this)
- I use [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) (or [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)) to speed up my websites. (Don't forget to exclude the revslider in the minify js: wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=4.6.92 => number depends on you'r version or revolution slider)

There are a lot of other things to keep in mind (version Wordpress, other plugins, hosting, ...)

Comment: I'm using cache plugins to speed up this site, and there is just few plugins beside revslider and visual composer. When I import their complete template, it works fine the problem is when I edit that template. Only then I'm having lag issues.

Comment: Did you use the layer position to position the slider? They suggest not to use negative values (authors from Revolution slider)

Comment: Yes, I'm using everything by their instructions